# Difficulty hosting subdomain with multiple dots

Tags: dns, proxy, ssl, nginx

I am attempting to host the S3 replacement service MinIO. When I use a subdomain with a dot in it (`console.s3.example.com` instead of `console.example.com`) I receive an SSL error `SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP`, while normal subdomains work. I use nginx proxy manager with lets encrypt to issue my SSL certs.

I have tried multiple browsers and the problem persists.

I tested my site with [SSLTest](https://ssllabs.com/ssltest) and the console.s3 domain failed while the console domain returned a rating of B on all 4 tests. Here is my SSLTest results:

[image]

I used these tutorials to install my services.

1. [MinIO](https://operators.urbit.org/manual/running/minio)
2. [NPM](https://www.the-digital-life.com/nextcloud-nginx-proxy-manager-in-10-minutes/)

How can I make console.s3 work?

Comment: Have you googled "SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP nginx".  There are over 2000 hits.  I found [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1363357) right off.  You make no mention of stuff you have tried so what do I know?

Comment: can you replicate with multiple browser brands? what do you get if you test your site with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ ? this error can have several causes, but if it affects multiple browsers, then it is likely that the issue is related to SNI configuration or bad TLS settings on the server (for instance protocols/ciphers so old that they are no longer supported by modern browsers). SNI is a technology to host multiple HTTPS sites on the same IP address, so that does seem like it could be related to your setup.

Comment: What web server? What ate the SAN lines for the domain? What does your config file say?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I have googled it, all of the answers I've been able to find are browser-side, not server-side. I believe it to be server-side as I have tried with multiple browsers (I also tried the link you posted).

Comment: so in what way precisely did the SSLtest fail. I wasn't interested in the pass/fail, but the diagnostic information it provides. can you show us your results? also can you confirm whether or not you are hosting multiple HTTPS sites on the same IP address with different certificates? if so, have you enabled SNI for your webserver?

Comment: @FrankThomas Thank you for your engagement so far. I updated my post with a link to my SSLTest result. I am running multiple webservers with different certs. The webserver I'm running that isn't this one (Nginx) has SNI enabled by default, but I've not been able to find out how to enable this on MinIO. I have been able to use the MinIO console while another webserver with a different cert is running, just not with the domain name I need to use.